# Is CBPeripherial writeValue thread safe in ios 5.0?

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

I want to connect multiple bluetooth LE peripheries to my iPad app in same time, and I want to be notified the characteristic changes and modified its characteristics using

> [CBPeripherial writeValue:forCharacteristic:type:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBPeripheral_Class/translated_content/CBPeripheral.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CBPeripheral/writeValue%3aforCharacteristic%3atype%3a)

Is it possible?

Should I put the handling of each peripheral for different threads?

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

It's up to you to set the dispatch queue for the delegate. writeValue is writing the remote peripheral's value. If you have multiple writes on the same remote peripheral, the underlying protocol layer (ATT) calls is synchronized at the framework (CoreBluetooth) level. If you are writing to different peripherals, then each of which is operating at a different communication channel. Either way, there is no thread safety concern.

But of course, if your delegates are accessing local objects from different threads, then you will need protect those objects if they are not thread safe.

Comment: I have separate service implementation for each peripheral.
So, if I have a songleton object which handle the peripheral discovering and if it finds a new peripheral than create a new service object for this pheripherial, wich delegate messages directly for a view. I think, there is no thread safety concern on this process, or?